# change font size if character more than specific number of characters

Tags: vuejs2

How can I change the font size if the name is more than 15 or 20 characters in vueJS?

Here's my code

```
<p class="name" v-if="roleProfile"><b>{{ roleProfile.company_name }}</b></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a computed property to add a class to the `<p>` tag based on the length of `roleProfile.company_name`:

```
computed: {
  profileClass() {
    let profileClass = "name";
    if (this.roleProfile.company_name.length > 15) {
      profileClass += " smallFont";
    }

    return profileClass;
  }
}
```

Then in your template:

```
<p :class="profileClass" v-if="roleProfile">
  <b>{{ roleProfile.company_name }}</b>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made a function and assigned it to my div with :style="{ fontSize: heroFontSize }"
Basically I used the reverse ratio, I have defined the minimum and maximum character sizes, and compared to the maximum and minimum number of characters. I have come to the conclusion thet for every 2.5 characters I have to decrease the size by 1px. So below you find the result.

```
heroFontSize() {
      //we map the font sizes between 60chars and 200 chars from 100px to 50px
      // there's a reverse ratio between character count and the font size
      var minSize = 60;
      var textLength = this.question.length;
      //for every 2.5 characters we decrease the size with 1px
      var multiplier = 2.5;
      return 100 - (textLength - minSize) / multiplier + "px";
    },
```